# How to find file size without stdio library?

Tags: c

I am trying to find the size of a file without using stdio library.
This way (see below) works perfectly, but I can't find a way to make that work without stdio library.

```
int getfilesize(const char *filename){

   int size;
   FILE *f;

   f=fopen(filename, "rb");

   //pointer check
   if(f==NULL){
      return (-1);
   }

   fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
   size = ftell(f);
   fclose(f);

   return(size);
}
```

Comment: You could use [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: `fopen` and friends *are* in `stdio` library.

Comment: @EugeneSh.he wants to do it _without_ stdio stuff

Comment: Hm. The most portable way would be *to use* `stdio`.

Comment: you could use system primitives like `open` and `seek`, would that be OK? why would you want to avoid stdio?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You can have branchiae instead :)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's late :)

Comment: If you don't use stdio, the code may be less portable, but it's certainly doable.  On a Unix system, the obvious solution is to use the `stat` system call.

Comment: `off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);` or `off64_t size = lseek64(fd, 0, SEEK_END);`  would be equivalent system calls, but using `stat` (also a system call) makes more sense.

Comment: stat works fine on windows as well. but sounds like XY problem.

Comment: thanks guys. I also found a way to do it. I use lseek to go to the beginning of the file i want to find it's size and then use lseek to end and the return value is the number of bytes. thanks all for your time.

Comment: I think you need [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) or [Posix API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html). huh..?